# How to notify when new insert occurs in sql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one page in one folder name as first/firstpage.php and I have another page in second folder as second/secondpage.php. In my firstpage.php I have form and one insert code in php and on second page i.e secondpage.php I have php code to display inserted data from first page. I want a notification alert to notify me on second page that insert has occurred.

Comment: You need to provide some representative code, it helps frame answers in the right context. Normally how you do this is by having your first page commit a record to a database and provide an identifier that can be used to retrieve it to the second page.

Comment: ya. that i was thinking too. but how to start and what identifier to set i am confused. wil u help me?

Comment: When you insert into a database you get an ID back out with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, though this presumes your table as an `id` column that's `AUTO_INCREMENT`. That's the textbook way to do this. On the receiving side use that to `SELECT ... WHERE id=?` to get the data back out.

Comment: It's worth noting this sort of stuff is handled out of the box in any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/), so if you're going at it from the ground up that's why you're having all these problems. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is pretty easy to pick up, there's tons of examples to work from, and something like this is very standard behaviour.

Comment: There are several approaches

1. Make an ajax call from your listing page , which return total number of records as a response . If the record is increased you can trigger some popup
2. Refresh your page periodically  to check the total records
3. Use websockets (socket.io is the easiest one).

Comment: how to fetch from receiver side?? select ... where id = ?

i have to put ? mark or any other id in that place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with multiple ways

- After insert post same data into your another function in which you are showing list.
- You can use trigger in this case.

  Table 1, Table 2

Now  whenever any data will be inserted into Table 1 than after it will store same data into another table and list will fetch data from table2. Once whenever new data inserted into table1 that before remove all data from table2.

Comment: so you mean to say that i have to create new sample table n apply trigger as 
Trigger name : notify 
Table : table 1
Time : after
Event : insert
Definition : insert code to table 2

​
Definer : ???? What to put here?

Comment: and after that trigger i have to check on second page that whether data is inserted in table 2. if yes notify and hen delete. else nothing

Comment: if you want to just notify then you can delete. and if you want to show until new data not insert into table 1 then before insert into table1 you have to truncate table2

Comment: i am getting error while creating trigger as " implicit/explicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: thank you for the idea. i made one dummy table and every insert query will insert in dummy table query's last id. and then on my second page i will check if any insert occured through that last id and then i'll throw alert and delete that data from dummy table.

Comment: since i got idea from your comments i am accepting this answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use web sockets

Theres sockets sample in php docs

http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: I am using windows 7 and my database is gator server database. sill it be compatible? and where to put that socket code? I never used sockets before. please help me in this.

Comment: Websockets is wildly over-kill here.